# wordpress: change the core table structure for ecommerce site

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes, hook-woocommerce

i have project that i need to integrate tables in different structure of wordpress. i am want to use woocommerce plugin and make it work with product table. i still want to preserve all woocommerce logic and features.
when thinking about that all i want to do is changing the way i want to get the data, i mean to the query. my question is, if there is a way to implement it with kind of service.
i thought about serviece with functionality:

1.disable the post meta request- i am still trying to figure out how to do it.

2.trigger hooks once before the request to DB trigger - this is where i will convert the query wordpress/woocommerce logic created to new structure that will fit my tables structure.
3.trigger hook once after i get response from request where i will convert it to structure worpdress/woocommerce need for using the original flow. 
how much it will be complicated and which hooks or filters should i use.

Comment: Why? If you want to change the way the data is retrieved that drastically maybe you should consider using the API instead?

Comment: But i want to preserve all wordpress feature and use the cms because of that i am searching a way of to change the Db without that effecting on wordpress flow